# Fragment distortion on Nexus 6p

Tags: android, android-fragments

Please see the screenshot for the weird distortion I'm getting when replacing fragment. It's working beautifully on other phones like OnePlus One & Android One, but this issue is occurring on the Nexus 6P.

There is a duplicate fragment beneath the real fragment. If I pull out the nav drawer slightly, it is pulled out on the underlying fragment as well. So it's not just a static, but an actual live fragment underneath.

I'm replacing fragment, not adding it. The fragment also has a background color.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((BaseActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(0).getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_left_out, R.anim.slide_right_out, R.anim.slide_right_in);
    transaction.replace(BaseActivity.getContainerIdForCurrentActivity(context), fragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

[image: ddd]

Comment: Which bg color the fragment have?

Comment: It's black with 0.8 alpha

Comment: Try to set another color and see what is the result.

Comment: If I increase the alpha to 1.0, it'll working fine, since it will cover the underlying frag completely. But why is this issue only occurring on 6p and not other devices? And why it's even an issue in the first place?

Comment: Because of screen and color resolution(pixels)